# How to join these two queries in Django?

Tags: django, django-queryset

I have query like this in Django:

```
shared_file = File.objects.filter(id__in= Share.objects.filter(users_id = log_id).values_list('files', flat=True)).annotate(count=Count('share__shared_user_id'))   
file1 = [i.file_name for i in shared_file]

shared_username = [User.objects.filter(id__in= Share.objects.filter(users_id = log_id, files__file_name=k).values_list('shared_user_id', flat=True)).values_list('username') for k in file1]
```

I want to join them so that I can loop over it and find the usernames with whom the file is shared.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`select_related()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.select_related) and fetch related objects in one query (and avoid list comprehensions with queries):

I assumed that use model definiton as in [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15474953/how-to-print-list-according-to-index-in-django-template):

```
class Share(models.Model):
    users = models.ForeignKey(User)
    files = models.ForeignKey(File)
    shared_user_id = models.IntegerField()
    shared_date = models.TextField()
```

You can fetch Shares with User and File in one shot using:

```
shares = Share.objects.select_related('users', 'files').filter(users_id = log_id).all()

for share in shares:
    share             # Share model
    share.users       # User model
    share.files       # File model
```

Answer (score 0):

Use itertools chain from the STL http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain

```
chain(file1, shared_username)
```